# Pass a list of vectors of arguments as quosures to a function with purrr and rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang

Sorry for the numerous prepositions in the title. Similar to [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62689612/how-do-i-pipe-into-or-include-an-additional-argument-within-a-list-of-quosures) I have a list of quosures/arguments I want to pass to a function like `dplyr::count`:

```r
library(rlang)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

q_list <- function(...) {
  enquos(...)
}

my_q_list <- q_list(
  c(cyl, sort = TRUE),
  c(cyl, gear, sort = TRUE)
)
my_q_list
#> <list_of<quosure>>
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^c(cyl, sort = TRUE)
#> env:  global
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^c(cyl, gear, sort = TRUE)
#> env:  global
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Using purrr and rlang, how do I pass and execute each quosure of this list to `count(mtcars, ...)`

So the end result is identical to:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
count(mtcars, cyl, sort = TRUE)
#>   cyl  n
#> 1   8 14
#> 2   4 11
#> 3   6  7
count(mtcars, cyl, gear, sort = TRUE)
#>   cyl gear  n
#> 1   8    3 12
#> 2   4    4  8
#> 3   6    4  4
#> 4   4    5  2
#> 5   6    3  2
#> 6   8    5  2
#> 7   4    3  1
#> 8   6    5  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps you need  `count(mtcars, !!! q_list(cyl, gear), sort = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that makes this difficult is the use of `c()` here. We really need some sort of `rlang` object to hold your parameters. Here's an altered function to generate your list

```
q_list <- function(...) {
  q <- enexprs(...)
  transenv <- new_environment(list(c=exprs))
  purrr::map(q, function(x) {
    eval_tidy(x, env = transenv)
  })
}
```

This takes your expressions and evaulates them treating `c()` like `enexprs()`. Then you can inject those values into your function call

```
my_q_list <- q_list(
  c(cyl, sort = TRUE),
  c(cyl, gear, sort = TRUE)
)

purrr::map(my_q_list, ~eval_tidy(quo(count(mtcars, !!!.x))))
```

This would have been easier if you just make the expressions in a list without using `c()`

```
my_q_list <- list(
  exprs(cyl, sort = TRUE),
  exprs(cyl, gear, sort = TRUE)
)
purrr::map(my_q_list, ~eval_tidy(quo(count(mtcars, !!!.x))))
```

Comment: Interesting, this mostly works, but sort = TRUE is evaluated to mutate another column, not as the sort argument to count.

Comment: @DavidRanzolin I did miss that. I'm kind of surprised by that. I've updated to use a workaround. I'll keep looking to see why that's the case.

Comment: Yes, I think it's related, but I was surprised select(mtcars, c(cyl, carb)) works fine but count(mtcars, c(cyl, carb)) fails.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` can be outside

```
library(purrr)
list(q_list(cyl), q_list(cyl, gear)) %>% 
  map(~ count(mtcars, !!! .x, sort = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#  cyl  n
#1   8 14
#2   4 11
3   6  7

#[[2]]
#  cyl gear  n
#1   8    3 12
#2   4    4  8
#3   6    4  4
#4   4    5  2
#5   6    3  2
#6   8    5  2
#7   4    3  1
#8   6    5  1
```